# How to stop a php foreach based on the session value, and the session was set after the beginning of foreach?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, foreach

> How to stop a foreach using codeigniter session, if session was set after than the foreach start it's not work.

```
foreach ($clintes as $cliente)
{
   $stop = $this->session->userdata('stop');
   if($stop == 1)
   {
      break;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: You are working with concurrent data, php can't do that

Comment: Where do you set your session ? I don't see any scenario where the session would change value while the loop is processing.